# use clean or pretty URLs for document library folders

Tags: 2013, document-library, url

In SharePoint 2013, when you are looking at files/folders in a document library the page URL is pretty cause it uses RootFolder=... Is it possible to change this behavior to use the clean/pretty URLs?

From this: `http://sp.company.com/sites/blah/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2Fblah%2Ffolder1%2Ffolder2&FolderCTID=0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000&View=%7123456789%212345%212345%212345%21234568936418%7D`

To this: `http://sp.company.com/sites/blah/Documents/folder1/folder2/`

Is there some setting that will make all URLs for document libraries look like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in SharePoint, folders are a theoretical construct. They're not really folders, so they don't really feature in the hierarchy of a URL.

Can't you use the friendly text of the link to show a, well, friendly text?

Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to make it easier when users/folks copy and paste URLs in to e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to click on 'Library' tab, then 'Library Settings'  you will notice a **nice clean** URL Labled "Web Address".

For example:

Web Address:
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/dept/IS/SuperTeam/Catchall/Forms/Catchall_DocLib_View.aspx

If I drill down a folder deeper from the top level where I have a butt-ton of documents stored, Righ-Click the elipses menu on a specific document and select **'Get a Link'**  use that address,  it's neat-ish and tidy-ish...  better than the 4 lines of gobbledy-gook.

https://xyz.sharepoint.com/:w:/s/dept/IS/SuperTeam/ESyGLO_JYMpGn6Ai47lUmSMBYAXBb7uNRdYdPEdM4KC2gA

Lastly, you can use a **URL shortener** like Bitly.  Throw in the gangly URL and Bitly will REALLY shorten it up.

From this: https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/dept/IS/SuperTeam/Catchall/Forms/Catchall_DocLib_View.aspx

To This:  https://bit_ly/2DMbYtm   (I changed bit.ly  to bit_ly because it would have violated URL rules in questions and responses here, this is not a real document anyways,  but just wanted to demonstrate URL shorteners)

Hope this might help!